# How to display a QDate-month with a different locale than system?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdate, qlocale

The function [`QDate::toString(const QString &format)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString) allows to display the month name with `MMM` (e.g. 'Jan' to 'Dec') or `MMMM` (e.g. 'January' to 'December').

But this function uses the system locale from `QLocale::system()` ([source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.cpp.html#_ZNK5QDate8toStringE11QStringView)).

What is the easiest way to display a `QDate` with a month name, for a specific QLocale ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `toString()` method of `QLocale` instead of `QDate`.

```
QDate d =  QDate::currentDate();
QList<QLocale> locales {QLocale(QLocale::Spanish),
            QLocale(QLocale::English),
            QLocale(QLocale::Dutch),
            QLocale(QLocale::Japanese),
            QLocale(QLocale::French),
            QLocale(QLocale::Chinese)};

QString format = "dd MMMM yyyy";

for(const QLocale locale: locales){
    qDebug()<<locale.toString(d, format);

}
```

output:

```
"16 octubre 2017"
"16 October 2017"
"16 oktober 2017"
"16 10月 2017"
"16 octobre 2017"
"16 十月 2017"
```